# bbcode tags formatting incorrectly in tinymce 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tinymce, bbcode, tinymce-4

I'm trying to get the order of bbcode tags to format correctly with tinymce 4.1.5.

When I set the text color and underline it, the closing tags get mixed up or it puts the text-decoration="underline" attribute in the color tag.

For instance, I get

```
[color="ff0000" text-decoration="underline"]some text[/color]
```

When it should be

```
[color="ff0000"][u]some text[/u][/color]
```

Or I may get
[color="ff0000"][u]some text[/color][u]

Here is my text area

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("TestTinyMce", "Content", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.TextArea("TextArea", Model.TextArea, new { @id = "TextArea", @class = "tinymce"   })
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
}
```

Here is the initialization:

```
    tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "bbcode,paste,textcolor"
    ],
    toolbar1: "undo redo |  bold italic underline forecolor |  link unlink  "
});
```

I'm checking the value when it reaches the controller after it's submitted. I'm trying to see if there is any configurations, plugins, or tricks I can use to cleanup this bbcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overriding the formatting with tinymce so it breaks up the spans. This way I don't get underline mixed in with color.

To handle the tag closing mismatch, I used the SaveContent event and just cleaned up the tags.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea.tinymce",
    theme: "modern",
    width: "100%",
    height: "250px",
    plugins: [
        "bbcode paste textcolor link"
    ],
    toolbar1: "undo redo  bold italic underline forecolor   link unlink  ",
    formats: {
        bold: { inline: 'strong', exact: true },
        italic: { inline: 'em', exact: true },
        underline: { inline: 'span', styles: { "text-decoration": "underline" }, exact: true },
        forecolor: { inline: 'span', styles: { color: '%value' }, exact: true }
    },
    // New event
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init', function (args) {
        });
        editor.on('SaveContent', function (e) {
            e.content = FixTags(e.content);
        });

    },
});
```